# Is line graph $ L(C_n) $ of cycle graph $ C_n $ isomorphic to $ C_n $ itself?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

I guess the answer is true. How can it be proved if it is true?

Answer (score 2):

A simple undirected graph is a cycle graph iff it is 2-regular and has only one connected component. Now, each edge in a cycle is incident to two other edges, hence $L(C_n)$ is 2-regular. Meanwhile, it is trivial that if $G$ has $c$ connected components with edges, then $L(G)$ has $c$ connected components. Using this fact we get that $L(C_n)$ has one connected component. Therefore, by the initial statement $L(C_n)$ is a cycle graph. Since $C_n$ has $n$ edges, $L(C_n)$ has $n$ vertices and is thus isomorphic to $C_n$.

Comment: What about $G = \{1,2,3\}$ and $E = \{12\}$.  Then $G$ has two components but $L(G)$ only one.

Comment: only one of those components has an edge

Comment: Yes, but it's still a graph where the number of components of $G$ and $L(G)$ are not the same.

Comment: I said $c$ is the number of components with edges in $G$

Comment: oh, I see.  I should really more carefully :)

Comment: You can also just give a direct isomorphism.